# How do you programmatically create layers in google maps engine lite using ajax and json

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-engine

How do you programatically create layers in google maps engine with json?  My end goal is to save the map to "my maps" and access from my mobile device for directions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>*Note from the future:* [Google has simply removed the Map Engine API and all its data in February, 2016.](https://mapsengine.google.com/about/index.html) Wonderful. This answer is now historical.</sub>

---

The Lite version of Maps Engine does not have an API, so this is not possible.

If you want to do it programatically, you can use the core [Maps Engine](http://maps.google.com/engine) product, which has an API ([documented here](http://developers.google.com/maps-engine/)).

Otherwise, the Android [Google Maps Engine app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.m4b) will load your maps on your mobile device.

Comment: I have looked through the API documentation, and have been trying to do an ajax post to send layer data to the api so that i can access them from the maps engine app on my device.  I have had no luck. any chance you have an example?

Comment: I must have skipped over that part of your question, at present the Maps Engine API doesn't support creating layers, only tables & table features.

Comment: So what are "tables and features"? are those like data points? if i have a bunch of addresses i want to include in a layer could i push them to tables and then include into a layer? guess i don't understand what tables and features really do?

Comment: Yep, a feature is a single data point, or row.  It will consist of a set of properties (e.g. id, name, description) and a geometry (a point, polygon, line, etc).  A table is a set of features.  A layer simply applies some style rules to a table (e.g. values below X should be blue).  It sounds like you could create the layer once and programatically update the table instead.

Comment: Oh and Google have mentioned that layer creation *will be available* through the API, though there is no mention of when.  https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-maps-engine-users/SPKqwa2m3yE/zZxoxCKQrCUJ

Comment: [Google has simply removed the Map Engine API and all its data in February, 2016.](https://mapsengine.google.com/about/index.html) Wonderful.